# stripe.txt not visible in my django project

Tags: django, stripe-payments, stripes

I am following the tutorial via the link below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncsCnC3Ynlw&t=13787s

I follow what the mentor did, but I don't have stripe.txt file in my django project, after I install stripe.

pip install stripe

the stripe.txt should be something like this.

No auth:4242424242424242

Auth: 4000000000000025000003155

Error: 400000000000000000999555

Can anyone advise me how to solve this?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the Stripe test cards. That file is just a reference file and it's not required for your application. Depending on what step you are looking for, but you can find it [here](https://github.com/veryacademy/django-ecommerce-project/blob/main/Part-03%20User%20Payment%20and%20Order%20Management/Final/stripe.txt) for example in part 3.

You can find more test card in Stripe official guide:

- Successful Payment Cards by brand () https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards
- Declined Payment https://stripe.com/docs/testing#declined-payments
- 3D Secure authentication cards: https://stripe.com/docs/testing#regulatory-cards

Use one of these cards number while doing your tests and simulations.